# Django - Searchbar in Listview | How to define and process it

Tags: python, django, listview, searchbar

### i'm totally new to django and python.
I would like to add a search bar working on my Listview page as I've seen on the Django admin-site.

I've seen a lot of django docs, many explainations and plenty of tutorials on the web but i have to say that I'm confused and could not find a solution for my problem.
What i want to do:
I have a page with a (class-based)ListView that presents 5 fields from my table.
I would like to add a search bar working on 2 of these 5 fields (object id and description) as i've seen on the Django admin-site.

Looking at the Docs and web these are a lot of different propositions to do that(queryset, filter, context, Q...). Personally I would like to work with the context. I tried to recover info from my searchbar but what I have implemented and tried since now is not working.
Could someone help me on this matter? What is the best practice and approach? Indications on how to manage this with some code exemple?
Thanks in advance!

#HTML

```
<form method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="q" value="" id="searchbar" autofocus>
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

#View
class AircraftListView(ListView):

```
model = Aircraft
paginate_by = 10

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AircraftListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    print(context)
    filter_set = Aircraft.objects.all()
    if self.request.GET.get('searchbar'):
        q = self.request.GET.get('searchbar')
        print('Hello I am on the right way')
        filter_set = filter_set.filter(q=self.aircraft.air_tailnumber)
    else:
        print('I took the wrong way')
        

    return context
```

Comment: I think your filter argument placements is wrong. It should be `filter_set = filter_set.filter(field_to_filter=q)`. So basically 'q' is the value from search bar. But in my opinion using `django-filter` package for filtering is the best solution for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tested it, but unfortunaltely it doesn't worrk for me.  Concerning django filter package, before installing it, I would rather code it myself if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't want to use django filter, I will try to give an example for your view. Instead of overriding `get_context_data` which is for extra context actually, override `get_queryset` method in your `ListView`. something like:

```py
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    search_text = request.GET.get("searchbar")
    if search_text:
        return queryset.filter(your_model_field=search_text)
    return queryset
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! At first  I was not able to solve it like in  this exemple but it helped me to clarify and understand a few things. In the end I cleared up all the def get context data  section as you suggested , but had some errors in the following tries with the queryset, so changed it a bit and actually worked!

Comment: Changed a bit the first part then actually specified the queries for the operator values and queryset result and now works like magic.

Comment: No problem, if any answer is useful or right solution, you can upvote or accept it. Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).